# Dato Incorrecto al Obtener valor COUNT de una consulta con rowCount PDO - PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, mvc, pdo

Estoy haciendo una consulta en el modelo de una aplicación web en `PHP` con `MVC`.  La idea es hacer una consulta en la cual al colocar el valor en `empresa_id` me aparezcan el total de filas con esa empresa, para esto he utilizado `COUNT()` en la consulta `SQL`.

El error que me arroja es que la empresa 14 tiene por ejemplo 8 usuarios, y la función solo me muestra un 1.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me aparezca el total de la empresa 14?

```
public function Contador(){   
    try{
    //Sentencia SQL.
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS codigo
                FROM nombre_tabla
                WHERE empresa_id = '14'";
        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stm->execute();
        return $stm->rowCount();
    } catch (Exception $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido!. Que error te da , podrías mostrarlo también.

Comment: Muchas gracias.  El error que me arroja es que la empresa 14 tiene por ejemplo 8 usuarios,  y la función solo me muestra un 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método [`rowCount`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php) de `PDO`  retorna las filas afectadas por una sentencia `DELETE`, `INSERT`, o `UPDATE` , Entonces al utilizar `SELECT` está obteniendo la cantidad de filas retornadas  que será siempre una *(según su consulta)* con el valor del `count` en la columna `codigo` , si desea obtener el este valor  puede hacerlo con  [`fetchColumn()`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) *(sin parámetros , si tuviese más columnas debería enviar el número de columna a obtener)*

```
return $stm->fetchColumn();
```

Yendo más a fondo, si el dato será dinámico , necesitará pasarse dicho dato a la consulta, para lo cuál lo más recomendable es preparar la sentencia correctamente para evitar ataques de Inyección SQL , *(posible resultado final)*

```
$id = 14 ; // $valor dinámico
//Sentencia SQL.
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS codigo
                FROM nombre_tabla
                WHERE empresa_id = ? ";
$stm = $conn->prepare($sql);
//pasamos el parámetro almacenado en $id
$stm->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stm->execute();
echo $stm->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación.  Con fetchColumn() funciono prefectamente.